# How to override methods safely

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, overriding

I have an abstract class that does a lot of hard work for child classes.

Each virtual method has some validation rules in it.

```
protected virtual void PrepareToStartGame(TimeSpan remainingTime, GameStarted response)
{
    if (IsGameActive != true)
    {
        Debug.LogError("There isn't an active game!");
        return;
    }

    if (gameStarted)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Game is already started!");
        return;
    }

    if (preparedForStart)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Game is already prepared to start");
        return;
    }

    if (RoomId != response.Game.RoomId)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Wrong GameStarted RoomId!");
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, whenever I override this method I should be able to override it safely. for example, this override has a bug in it as it does not check for validation rules:

```
protected override void PrepareToStartGame(TimeSpan remainingTime, GameStarted response)
{
    base.PrepareToStartGame(remainingTime, response);

    WaitingForPlayersPanel.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

I'm thinking about a walkaround for this problem that helps me not to worry about this kind of bugs in the future.

What do you suggest for this?

I know I can return a bool for success or create a validation method to check in every overridden method. But I'm looking for a better solution.

There are some valid cases that some events from the server may cause wrong method calls so I cannot throw exceptions here and should just ignore them.

Comment: What do you mean by safely? Which validation rules are you talking about?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the first code snippet has some my own validation codes.

Comment: Honestly the only solution that gives you such security is a weaver. https://github.com/Fody/Fody

Comment: Whu do you think that validation rules won't work with `base` call? Is there is something specific with `gameStarted`, `preparedForStart` and other conditions?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Look at the second snippet `WaitingForPlayersPanel.gameObject.SetActive(false);` this line of code will be run even if validation rules are not met and this clearly is a bug.

Comment: @Moira So you suggest that I should move validation checks to child class? what if that in future that child class extended? I mean a chain of method overriding.

Comment: You can throw an exception then, instead of `Debug.LogError`. Or pass error/validation handler as class/method parameter

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski throwing exceptions seem to be the best choice but unfortunately there are some valid cases that some events from the server may cause wrong method calls so I cannot throw exceptions here.

Comment: Why don't you use proxy design pattern? it let you handle some functionality before execute inner object code.

Comment: @amirhosseinghorbani proxy seems to be a good fit here, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just "reverse" the dependency (basically implementing [template method](https://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern)), making this method nonvirtual and introducing a new one which is:

```
protected void PrepareToStartGame(TimeSpan remainingTime, GameStarted response)
{
    if (IsGameActive != true)
    {
        Debug.LogError("There isn't an active game!");
        return;
    }

    if (gameStarted)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Game is already started!");
        return;
    }

    if (preparedForStart)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Game is already prepared to start");
        return;
    }

    if (RoomId != response.Game.RoomId)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Wrong GameStarted RoomId!");
        return;
    }
    ...

    PrepareToStartGameInner(remainingTime, response);
}   

protected virtual void PrepareToStartGameInner(remainingTime, response) {};
```

And in a child class:

```
protected override void PrepareToStartGameInner(TimeSpan remainingTime, GameStarted response)
{
    WaitingForPlayersPanel.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: @AminSojoudi was glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

I would say, if you want to notify the validation error, you should throw the custom error from the method. Caller should handle it gracefully based on the workflow requirement.

Comment: This should be the right answer but in my case, as I mentioned before, there are some valid server events that call this method and should be ignored. this is a limitation of mine and you answer is generally correct.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't want to give control to inherited method, don't declare it virtual or overridable.

When you want to give partial control, raise events instead of making the method virtual or overridable. The inherited class can then handle the events instead of overriding the method. And they always have the choice to not handle the event if they don't need to.

e.g.

```
    public event EventHandler PreparingToStartGame;
    public event EventHandler PreparedToStartGame;

    protected void OnPrepareToStartGame(TimeSpan remainingTime, GameStarted response)
    {

        PreparingToStartGame?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());

        if (IsGameActive != true)
        {
            Debug.LogError("There isn't an active game!");
            return;
        }

        if (gameStarted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Game is already started!");
            return;
        }

        if (preparedForStart)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Game is already prepared to start");
            return;
        }

        if (RoomId != response.Game.RoomId)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Wrong GameStarted RoomId!");
            return;
        }
        //......

        PreparedToStartGame?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());

    }
```

I used `new EventArgs()` just for demo above. But you can create a class inherited from EventArgs and use it instead, if you want to give/take parameter values to/from the method.

HTH.

Comment: "When you don't want to give control to inherited method, don't declare it virtual or overridable." Perfect. Thanks